# How do I convert the following var Scala code into vals?

Tags: scala

```
var exit: String = expensiveOperation
if (exit.contains(...)) exit = somethingElse
```

The key is I only wish to call

expensiveOperation

once since it consumes many clock cycles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don’t want to expose the other `val`, do it inline:

```
val exit = {
  val result = expensiveOperation
  if (result.contains(...)) somethingElse
  else result
}
```

or, if you like

```
val exit = expensiveOperation match {
  case res if res.contains(...) => somethingElse
  case res if res.contains(...) => somethingBetter
  // ...
  case res => res
}
```

Answer (score 8):

a silly solution: just introduce another val.

```
   val expected = expensiveOperation 
   val exit = if(expected.contains(...)) expected else something else
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: extract a method.

```
def exitValue(...): String = {
    val exit: String = expensiveOperation
    if (exit.contains(...)) somethingElse else exit
}

val exit = exitValue(...)
```

Comment: You could write that inline without an extra method.